# Ajax jquery links may not work depending on folder level of originating page in site

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery Tab on all pages at various levels in the site structure. The Tab content is loaded by AJAX using LOAD call pulling content from various tags on another html page.

The AJAX content in the Tab contains a link:/contact.html.

If the link /contact.html is activated from a page residing in root directory e.g /Homes.html everything works fine.

If the AJAX link /contact.html is activated from a page residing in a folder down from the root directory e.g /Homes/HomeA/HomeA.html the link breaks and the URL in the address bar shows /Homes/HomeA/Contact.html.

I thought the / in front of the path caused the path to be Absolute meaning - in my mind - that no matter where the calling page resides in the site structure the search for the linked page would start from the site root and work down where necessary.

Can anyone tell me - in words of one syllable - what I am doing wrong. I am new to AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Absolute paths, will be of the form `http://myserver/path/to/file.html`
while relative ones will be of the form `path/to/file.html`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think if you re-read the page to which you refereed me you will find that whether the path has the full  domain name http://myserver/path/to/file.html or the shorter version of /path/to/file.html without the domain name, they are both Absolute paths. A relative path would be to leave off the initial / as in path/to/file.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have found and fixed my problem simply with a / (which I had carelessly omitted) in front of the path.

I think if you re-read the page to which you kindly referred me, you will find that both 'http://myserver/path/to/file.html' with the full domain name and '/path/to/file.html' without the domain name but with the / in front are both Absolute paths. They both point to the site root. A Relative path would be 'path/to/file.html' without the domain name or the first /.

Comment: This is not my day. I am tripping over my own messages! Yes, my problem was of my own causing. I omitted the first / in front of the path thereby making it a relative path instead of the absolute path I thought I was creating. Once I replaced the initial / everything worked fine. Many thanks for your help